# A 3D cube on html canvas,I want the origin lines to extend and represent the x,y,z axis and altogether to work like Miller Indices experiment, please

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I Basically want the axis to extend as x,y,z axis and then either by clicking on the respective line or by taking input from the user through input element I want the co-ordinates to be marked and then join the co-ordinates through a line and fill them.Basically I want to perform the miller indices experiment and to understand it I am even attaching a 2d pic which I want to represent in 3d form [2d Image Form how I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DiL2.png) Please help me out....Thankyou
1)The Html Code Followed By The Javascript

```
Html Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/3DCube.js"></script>
<body>
<h3> Miller Indices Cube</h3>
Use the up-down-right-left arrow keys and the "a" and "z" keys to rotate the shape in 3D 
alongth x,y,z axis.</br></br>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="650" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<h2 id="status">0 | 0</h2>
</body>
</html>


JavaScript Code
window.onload=function(){
//access canvas and its context
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,1)';

//set initial angles for cubes position
var Qx=Math.PI/4;
var Qy=Math.PI/3;
var Qz=Math.PI/4;
var dx=0;
var dy=0;
var dz=0;

//length of the cube edges
var SIZE=75;
var NewSIZE=105;
//array that will hold all the cube vertices
var vertices=[];

//utility function
function addPoint(x,y,z) {
    return [x,y,z]
}

//create the vertices of the cube and put them in their array
vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));

vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));

vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));

vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));

drawCube();

//event listener on the keyboard
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkIfKeyPressed, false);

//check if up down right left a z keys have been pressed
//increment or decrement the respective x,y,z rotational parameters
function checkIfKeyPressed(e) {
    var step=Math.PI/4320;
    
    if (e.keyCode == "39") {//right key
        dy=dy+step;
        
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == "37") {//left key
            dy=dy-step;
            
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == "40") {//up key
            dx=dx+step;
            
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == "38") {//down key
            dx=dx-step;
            
    }
    else if (e.keyCode=="65") {//a key
            dz=dz+step;
            
    }
    else if (e.keyCode=="90") {//z key
            dz=dz-step;
            
    };
    
    e.preventDefault();//in case up down accidentally interpreted for scrolling
    updateCube();
    
    

}

//function that updates the cube 
function updateCube(){
    var rate=0.999;//this parameter is responsible for the slow dying off effect of rotations
    
    dx=t=rate*dx;
    Qx=Qx+dx;
    dy=rate*dy;
    Qy=Qy+dy;
    dz=rate*dz;
    Qz=Qz+dz;
    drawCube();
        
    //console.log("Qx,Qy,Qz",Qx,Qy,Qz)
    //console.log("dx,dy,dz",dx,dy,dz)
    
    //key operation to create an animation.  This is what gives the sustaining movement.
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCube)
    
}

//this is the function that projects 3D coordinates to the 2D canvas
//it took me a whole summer some years ago to figure these transformations
function project3D(x,y,z) {
    var xRotQz=x*Math.cos(Qz)+y*Math.sin(Qz);
    var yRotQz=y*Math.cos(Qz)-x*Math.sin(Qz);
    var zRotQz=z;
    var xRotQzQx=xRotQz;
    var yRotQzQx=yRotQz*Math.cos(Qx)+zRotQz*Math.sin(Qx);
    var zRotQzQx=zRotQz*Math.cos(Qx)-yRotQz*Math.sin(Qx);
    var xRotQzQxQy=xRotQzQx*Math.cos(Qy)+zRotQzQx*Math.sin(Qy);
    var yRotQzQxQy=yRotQzQx;
    //var zRotQzQxQy=zRotQzQx*Math.cos(Qy)-xRotQzQx*Math.sin(Qy);
    return [xRotQzQxQy,yRotQzQxQy]
}

//function that draws the cube
function drawCube(){
    //console.log("drawCube");
    
    //these clear the canvas of previous traces
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,650,400);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,650,400)
    
    var verticesPixLoc=[];
    //vertex coordinates in 3D are first projected to 2D and then transformed into pixel location
    //this latter is needed as (0,0) of canvas is not at the center of the canvas but at upper left
    for(var i=0;i<vertices.length;i++)
    {
        var xyLoc=project3D(vertices[i][0],vertices[i][1],vertices[i][2]);
        var pixLoc=transformXYtoPixels(xyLoc[0],xyLoc[1]);
        verticesPixLoc.push(pixLoc);
        
        //give vertices a bit of a circular shape
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(pixLoc[0],pixLoc[1],4,0,2*Math.PI);
        
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        
        
    }
    
    //draw the cube edges
    for(var i=0;i<vertices.length-1;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(verticesPixLoc[i][0],verticesPixLoc[i][1]);
        ctx.lineTo(verticesPixLoc[i+1][0],verticesPixLoc[i+1][1]);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

//this function transforms (x,y) of cartesian plane to proper pixel location of canvas with (0,0)
//at the upper left
function transformXYtoPixels(x,y) {
        return [x+650/2,-y+400/2]
}
}
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
    //access canvas and its context
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,1)';
    
    //set initial angles for cubes position
    var Qx=Math.PI/4;
    var Qy=Math.PI/3;
    var Qz=Math.PI/4;
    var dx=0;
    var dy=0;
    var dz=0;
    
    //length of the cube edges
    var SIZE=75;
    var NewSIZE=105;
    //array that will hold all the cube vertices
    var vertices=[];
    
    //utility function
    function addPoint(x,y,z) {
        return [x,y,z]
    }
    
    //create the vertices of the cube and put them in their array
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));
    
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
    
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));
    
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,-SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,-SIZE));
    vertices.push(addPoint(-SIZE,SIZE,SIZE));
    
    drawCube();
    
    //event listener on the keyboard
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkIfKeyPressed, false);
    
    //check if up down right left a z keys have been pressed
    //increment or decrement the respective x,y,z rotational parameters
    function checkIfKeyPressed(e) {
        var step=Math.PI/4320;
        
        if (e.keyCode == "39") {//right key
            dy=dy+step;
            
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == "37") {//left key
                dy=dy-step;
                
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == "40") {//up key
                dx=dx+step;
                
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == "38") {//down key
                dx=dx-step;
                
        }
        else if (e.keyCode=="65") {//a key
                dz=dz+step;
                
        }
        else if (e.keyCode=="90") {//z key
                dz=dz-step;
                
        };
        
        e.preventDefault();//in case up down accidentally interpreted for scrolling
        updateCube();
        
        
    
    }
    
    //function that updates the cube 
    function updateCube(){
        var rate=0.999;//this parameter is responsible for the slow dying off effect of rotations
        
        dx=t=rate*dx;
        Qx=Qx+dx;
        dy=rate*dy;
        Qy=Qy+dy;
        dz=rate*dz;
        Qz=Qz+dz;
        drawCube();
            
        //console.log("Qx,Qy,Qz",Qx,Qy,Qz)
        //console.log("dx,dy,dz",dx,dy,dz)
        
        //key operation to create an animation.  This is what gives the sustaining movement.
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCube)
        
    }
    
    //this is the function that projects 3D coordinates to the 2D canvas
    //it took me a whole summer some years ago to figure these transformations
    function project3D(x,y,z) {
        var xRotQz=x*Math.cos(Qz)+y*Math.sin(Qz);
        var yRotQz=y*Math.cos(Qz)-x*Math.sin(Qz);
        var zRotQz=z;
        var xRotQzQx=xRotQz;
        var yRotQzQx=yRotQz*Math.cos(Qx)+zRotQz*Math.sin(Qx);
        var zRotQzQx=zRotQz*Math.cos(Qx)-yRotQz*Math.sin(Qx);
        var xRotQzQxQy=xRotQzQx*Math.cos(Qy)+zRotQzQx*Math.sin(Qy);
        var yRotQzQxQy=yRotQzQx;
        //var zRotQzQxQy=zRotQzQx*Math.cos(Qy)-xRotQzQx*Math.sin(Qy);
        return [xRotQzQxQy,yRotQzQxQy]
    }
    
    //function that draws the cube
    function drawCube(){
        //console.log("drawCube");
        
        //these clear the canvas of previous traces
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,650,400);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,650,400)
        
        var verticesPixLoc=[];
        //vertex coordinates in 3D are first projected to 2D and then transformed into pixel location
        //this latter is needed as (0,0) of canvas is not at the center of the canvas but at upper left
        for(var i=0;i<vertices.length;i++)
        {
            var xyLoc=project3D(vertices[i][0],vertices[i][1],vertices[i][2]);
            var pixLoc=transformXYtoPixels(xyLoc[0],xyLoc[1]);
            verticesPixLoc.push(pixLoc);
            
            //give vertices a bit of a circular shape
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pixLoc[0],pixLoc[1],4,0,2*Math.PI);
            
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fill();
            
            
        }
        
        //draw the cube edges
        for(var i=0;i<vertices.length-1;i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(verticesPixLoc[i][0],verticesPixLoc[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(verticesPixLoc[i+1][0],verticesPixLoc[i+1][1]);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
    
    //this function transforms (x,y) of cartesian plane to proper pixel location of canvas with (0,0)
    //at the upper left
    function transformXYtoPixels(x,y) {
            return [x+650/2,-y+400/2]
    }
}


function initCanvas(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
        var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        status.innerHTML = mouseX+" | "+mouseY;
    });
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
        // alert(mouseX+" | "+mouseY);
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.fillRect(mouseX-15, mouseY-15, 30, 30);
    });
}
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    initCanvas();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/3DCube.js"></script>
<body>
<h3> Miller Indices Cube</h3>
Use the up-down-right-left arrow keys and the "a" and "z" keys to rotate the shape in 3D alongth x,y,z axis.</br></br>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="650" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<h2 id="status">0 | 0</h2>

</body>
</html>
```